# Return all results from Observable chain

Tags: javascript, rxjs

In my Angular application i'm trying to achieve the following

1. Execute `Observable` A
2. When A completes, execute `Observable` B, using the result of A
3. When B completes, return the result of **both** A and B

Without the 3rd point, this would be quite simple i guess, i would do something like this:

```
this.myService.getData()
  .pipe(
    flatMap(firstResult => this.myService.getMoreData(firstResult.someField))
  ).subscribe(secondResult => {
      // process the data
  });
```

The problem is this way i only have access to `secondResult` in the end, but i need `firstResult` as well.

I'm not an expert in RxJS observables, so i'd really appreaciate any advice on how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just map the second result to an array of both results.

```
this.myService.getData()
  .pipe(
    concatMap(firstResult => this.myService.getMoreData(firstResult.someField).pipe(
      map(secondResult => [firstResult, secondResult]),
    ))
  ).subscribe(([first, second]) => ...);
```